# Como funciona o .pipe() no Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, stream

Estou com uma dúvida sobre como funciona o `.pipe()`. Vi vídeos e li a documentação, mas não tenho certeza de como ele funciona.

Pelo o que eu entendi, ele basicamente pega as informações de uma `readableStream` e repassa isso para uma `writeableStream`, mas não tenho certeza se sei utilizar ele da maneira correta. Para esclarecer melhor o que estou dizendo vou colocar um código meu que deu errado:

```
const fs = require('fs')
const http = require('http')

const port = 8000
const file = './file.txt'

const readStream = fs.createReadStream(file)


const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
  res.on('pipe', fileContent => console.log(fileContent.toString()))
  readStream.pipe(res)
})

server.listen(port, () => console.log('Server is Runing...'))
```

Meu objetivo nessa parte era criar um servidor http e passar como resposta o conteúdo de dentro do arquivo pelo console (obs: no arquivo só tem um texto qualquer de uma linha). Meu servidor roda, porém nada aparece no console. Eu queria entender o que pode estar dando de errado pois não sei como receber o conteúdo do arquivo que enviei.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Basicamente, o método `pipe` "direciona" o fluxo de uma *readable stream* para uma *writable stream*. No caso da pergunta, o `pipe` está enviado os "pacotes" da *read stream* do arquivo para a *write stream* do servidor HTTP.

---

Na verdade, a *stream* funciona corretamente na *primeira* requisição.

Note que você está criando a *read stream* *fora* do *server handler*, de modo que, na primeira requisição, a *stream* será totalmente consumida. Assim, a partir da segunda requisição, não haverá mais o que ler, uma vez que todos os dados já terão sido esgotados.

É ideal, portanto, que você crie uma *read stream* para *cada* requisição. Algo assim:

```
const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
  res.on('pipe', () => console.log('Pipe chamado.'));

  const readStream = fs.createReadStream(file);
  readStream.pipe(res);
});
```

Note agora que uma nova *read stream* será criada para cada requisição. Observa também que modifiquei o `console.log` uma vez que o método `toString` não faz, nesse caso, o que você pensa.

O evento `pipe` é chamado com um parâmetro do tipo [`stream.Readable`](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_class_stream_readable). Portanto, se você quiser imprimir no console os dados lidos, poderá fazer algo como:

```
const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
  res.on('pipe', (src) => {
    src.on('data', (chunk) => {
      console.log(chunk.toString('utf8'));
    });
  });

  const readStream = fs.createReadStream(file);
  readStream.pipe(res);
});
```